# How to generate dynamically ngModel with *ngFor in Angular2?

Tags: html, loops, angular, angular-ngmodel, ngfor

This has been been baffling me since two days , how to have a new `ngModel` for every new iteration within an `*ngFor` loop ? the idea is that i load a list of questions, within every question I have 2 propositions , here is the html

```
 <div *ngFor="#qt of listQuestion">

<h3 class="uk-accordion-title" >{{qt.wordingQ}}</h3>

 <div class="uk-accordion-content">
    
<input type="checkbox"  id="0" [(ngModel)]="selected"  (Change)="cbChange($event)"/>

<label for="0" class="inline-label" > <b>{{qt.lpo[0]}}</b></label><br>
    
<input type="checkbox"  id="1" [(ngModel)]="selected_1" (Change)="cbChange_1($event)"/>

<label for="1" class="inline-label"><b>{{qt.lpo[1]}}</b></label><br>
    
    
                                   </div></div>
```

This will work smoothly only if u have **one question** in the `listQuestion`, if there is more than a question , once I will check a `proposition` (e.g : `lpo[0]`) of the first Question all the other first propositions (**first** because the index of `lpo = 0`) of other questions will be selected
Here is an image illustrating the issue:

[image]

Any help please ?

Comment: Same issue with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple, you have to make sure that json contains appropriate `true or false` field as you are going to deal with `checkbox`.

With `ngFor` i'd use `ngModel` like this way,

```
[(ngModel)]="qt.lpo[0]"  //qt.lpo has to be true or false
// Answer1, Answer2  you can manage separately 

[(ngModel)]="qt.lpo[1]" //qt.lpo creates new instance for each iteration of ngFor loop.
```

This way it creates different `ngModel` for each questions. But you have to make sure that `qt.lpo` field should contain true or false.

Answer (score 2):

Each ngModel need to be assigned to different variable. That's not the case in your example, because you are using only two variables (`selected`, `selected_1`). Object Oriented programming to the rescue! Create new class Question and new class Answer. Question should have inner array of Answers. Then use two ngFors to iterate over Questions and their Answers.

```
export class Question {
    public text:string;
    public answers:Answer[];
}

export class Answer{
    public text:string;
    public selected:boolean;
}

<div *ngFor="let q of questions">
    {{q.text}}
    <div *ngFor="let a of q.answers">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="a.selected">{{a.text}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can then initalize questions array like this:

```
questions:Question[] = [
    {
        text: "What do you want?",
        answers: [
            {
                "text": "Nothing",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "text": "Something",
                "selected": false
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

This way you can have uneven number of answers if you want